# SQL database publishing

Tags: github, github-actions, dacpac

I am having CI/CD for .net project, in YML file I am having msbuild command which in turn does the build of the solution and creates .dacpac file.

Below is the build command in one of the YML file which is responsible for creating dacpac file:

```
msbuild /restore /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=TEST_Build /p:Configuration=Release myDotNet.sln
```

Now, for the target SQL server we can't have Sysadmin role on the given server because of compliance issue. therefore, we need to perform this task without sysadmin role as we have already a database created there and the dacpac deployment should be differential/updation rather the creational

Here is the code for .dacpac deployment we are using:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:$dacpacFilePath /Profile:$publishProfileFilePath /p:BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges=True /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions" /TargetConnectionString:'Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=${{ secrets.QA_USERNAME}};Password=${{ secrets.QA_PASSWORD }}'
```

Please note that if we give sysadmin role it does deployment, but if have just DBOwner role it does not work and fails with error below:

> The object [mydb] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
> Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 User does not have permission to perform this action.

Can anyone help me with differential deployment here rather than creating a table, procedure, etc every time we do the deployment?

UPDATE:
Here is the publish option for QA:
[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to tweak the command that creates the dacpac file. Can you add that to the question?

Comment: I did that, Please see original question. @GregHNZ

Comment: The trick is going to be in the publishing profile.  This is generally created by right-clicking on the project and choosing publish (or similar). I'd be looking at what you get when you click on the "Advanced" button. This page has the only screenshot I've seen on that: https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2020/04/databases-in-devops-publishing-profile.html

Comment: Added snaphshot for the same